# How to hide app title until localization is forced?

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-actionbar

I have an action bar in my app which shows the app title. I also have localization. My problem is the moment I start the application, the title (for main launcher activity) appear in **wrong localization** then the activity looks like it refreshed and the title gets fixed to the correct localization.

The application and mainActivity tag (in manifest) use the string app_name, the problem is the delay. There is like 1 second delay till it is fixed.

How can I fix it by showing correct title (localization) or hide it till I see that localization is done?

I use this code to force localization in the `onCreate()` of the mainActivity

```
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(Globals.getLanguage(this));
conf.setLayoutDirection(conf.locale);
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Simply having the app title as a `@string/app_title`, translated in its own `strings.xml` in the `values-XX` folder should do the trick.

Comment: the application and mainActivity tag use the string, the problem is the delay. There is like 1 second delay till it is fixed.

Comment: @NicolasSimon Look at his code-  he's overriding the locale to a new one for his app only.  That's why the strings.xml alone isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd honestly advise against the entire approach you're taking.  People know that to change languages you change the phone's locale, I don't see value in having an app specific override.  But if you're going to do this-  set a blank string as your app name, then override the name after you set the locale via `getActionBar().setTitle()`

If the blank name has other side effects (and it might, now that I'm thinking about it that may be what the launcher uses), try setting it to be blank as the first line of your onCreate instead.  That may be soon enough to stop it from showing.

Comment: I usually don't like to force locale like you said, but the the application requirements needs it. If I set the label empty in manifest, it will affect the launcher icon text. I tried to set title for action bar 1st line in onCreate, but didn't help.

Comment: It seems there will be a small delay specially for the Title in ActionBar, Best way is to do that while adjust config in the Splash screen.